# Programmatically set TSQLConnection properties

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Using **TSQLConnection** component, If I set the **Driver** property to **DataSnap** is there a way to manually set properties for that driver in code?

e.g. **CommunicationProtocol** or **CommunicationIPVersion**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Any property that can be changed through Object Inspector at design-time can also be changed at runtime.

Comment: @SilverWarior:  True, but the OP's q was "how", not "whether".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it is not that straightforward as SilverWarior describes. The problem is that those properties are driver specific and are not directly accessible from TSQLConnection. OK, here is a way:

```
var
  dbxProps: TDBXDatasnapProperties;
begin
  Assert(SQLConnection1.DriverName = 'DataSnap', 'Driver must be DataSnap');
  dbxProps := SQLConnection1.ConnectionData.Properties as TDBXDatasnapProperties;
  dbxProps.CommunicationProtocol := 'tcp/ip';
  dbxProps.CommunicationIPVersion := 'IPv6';
end;
```

Comment: You *should* use the `TSQLConnection.Params` property instead of type-casting the `TSQLConnection.ConnectionData.Properties` directly.

Comment: Remy's answer is better. Yours introduces a dependency on the driver being only DataSnap, while Remy's will work for any driver (adjusting the param names accordingly, of course). Not downvoting; just pointing it out.

Comment: @KenWhite, I know that using the param names is more flexible, but the question is very specific. Actually the TDBXDataSnapProperties internally uses those parameter names, too. If you have to deal with different drivers at once, the general approach might be better, but in this specific case I personally prefer the shown approach. At least you can use code completion to get the parameter names right. Helps to avoid typos.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that made it specific. It asks how to set TSQLConnection properties in code, and names a couple of typical properties. Remy's answer shows exactly how to do that, in a more generic way, and shows how to get the proper parameter names (which can be copied/pasted directly from the string list editor, which avoids typos as well). But as I said, I'm not downvoting. Your answer technically is one correct (albeit not *proper*, IMO) solution. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, seems to be a matter of taste, but if you insist that using the param names is superior, then I suggest using the constants from Data.DBXCommon instead of literals. Anyway, also these only make sense when the driver is set to DataSnap (which was clearly stated in the question, btw - and it is a special one). So even using the params with the propnames still requires to know the driver type. Note, that in the quote posted in Remys answer there is only one parameter mentioned common to all drivers. Sorry, but I still see no advantage in doing so. I guess, we agree to disagree here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`TSQLConnection.Params`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.Params) property for that purpose:

> Lists the connection parameters.
>
> **Params** is a TStrings object listing the connection parameters. Each entry in the string list has the form
>
> ```
> Name=Value
> ```
>
> where Name is the name of the parameter and Value is its value. If you are using named connection configurations (the [ConnectionName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.ConnectionName) property), the values for each parameter are loaded from the dbxconnections.ini file when you set `ConnectName`.
>
> **At design time, you can set parameter values using the string list editor by double-clicking the Params property in the Object Inspector**. Any new values you set override the values loaded when you set [ConnectionName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.ConnectionName), unless you load the connection configuration at run time using [LoadParamsFromIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.LoadParamsFromIniFile) or [LoadParamsOnConnect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.LoadParamsOnConnect).
>
> **The particular parameters that appear depend on the database server. The Params property is initialized to include a string for each parameter when you set the [`DriverName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.DriverName) property**. One particular parameter, `Database`, is required for all servers. Its value depends on the server you are using. For example, with InterBase, `Database` is the name of the .gdb file, while with MySQL, it is the database name that was assigned by the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

For example:

```
SQLConnection1.DriverName := 'DataSnap';
SQLConnection1.Params.Values['CommunicationProtocol'] := 'tcp/ip';
SQLConnection1.Params.Values['CommunicationIPVersion'] := 'IPv6';`
```

Comment: It might help to note that setting the `Driver` (at least once) in the IDE will populate the SQLConnection.Params for that particular server, and then clicking the Params ellipsis (...) button will show the available parameter names and their default values, which makes a useful reference.

Comment: @KenWhite: that is actually stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.Params). I have added the quote to my answer.